# How can I let folder names display bold in Console2?

Tags: windows-7, text-formatting, console2

I am developing in Windows and am an active user of Console2. Is it possible for me to have my folder names show up in bold as opposed to being similar in formatting with my other files?

[image]

`Audtion` and `Premiere Pro` are folders, but `test.file` is not. How can I let Audition and Premiere Pro show in bold?

Comment: `Folder names`? Where?

Comment: @Maximus I uploaded an image. Does that help?

Comment: Console2 can't do that. But you may switch to ConEmu: http://i.imgur.com/FyRrqn1.png